# why php array (not like python) is both list and dict?

Tags: php

Since moving from Python to PHP, I find that the array, 'dict' in PHP , implements both list and dict:

$numlist = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$cat_and_mouse = array("tom"=>12, "jerry"=> 2);

and the frustrating array funcitons:

some of them should apply on a list, while others on a dict.

> array_​chunk array_​column array_​combine array_​count_​values
>   array_​diff_​assoc array_​diff_​key array_​diff_​uassoc
>   array_​diff_​ukey array_​diff array_​fill_​keys array_​fill
>   array_​filter array_​flip array_​intersect_​assoc
>   array_​intersect_​key array_​intersect_​uassoc array_​intersect_​ukey
>   array_​intersect array_​key_​exists array_​keys array_​map
>   array_​merge_​recursive array_​merge array_​multisort array_​pad
>   array_​pop array_​product array_​push array_​rand array_​reduce
>   array_​replace_​recursive array_​replace array_​reverse array_​search
>   array_​shift ...

List and HashMap are quite different in most language, WHY PHP mix them together?

Comment: I understand talking about the design of programming language is offensive, I just need a reason why php doing so.

Comment: Because PHP has the best arrays.  they are hash maps.

Comment: Well, at last I moved to Java, where List<?> and Map<?> are different interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in PHP are **always** associative, as by the [**very definition**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) a PHP array is an ordered map, which associates values to keys.

In fact, if you disseminate your example, you'll find that your first array maps keys to sequential indexes:

```
$numlist = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var_dump($numlist);
```

Results in:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
```

Whereas

```
$cat_and_mouse = array("tom" => 12, "jerry" => 2);
var_dump($cat_and_mouse);
```

Results in:

```
array (size=2)
  'tom' => int 12
  'jerry' => int 2
```

Omitting the key simply creates the key for you automatically, starting with `0`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I understand this feature, perhaps php designer thought that the pure List data structure is not a must

Comment: The whole point of having a key-value pair is integral to the PHP language; to retrieve a particular value **from** an array, you need to access it via its key. For example, to retrieve the value `2` from the second array I'd reference the `jerry` key: `echo $cat_and_mouse['jerry']`. It works the same way when you don't supply a key; the value `4` is the 4th item in the `$numlist` array so I need **some** way of accessing it given that knowledge. I'd use the `3` key which was automatically generated (like `echo $numlist[3]`). It's the third key rather than the fourth because we index from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP is the best programming language... \s

Answer (score 0):

2 years passed.
2 years ago, I moved from python to PHP, and 10 months ago, I moved from PHP to Java.
Great thanks to Java, everything is so neat and elegant, now I use Spring Boot to host my application, use Spring Data and Hibernate to persist my data, and there is Java 8 stream parallel to use multicore CPU. and the great maven, eclipse...

I can't believe I waste 2 years in PHP. I hope I never met it.